# PostgreSQL from E-R to correct trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, entity-relationship

I have this E-R Diagram: [image: E-R Diagram]
I've done the SQL translation, and I have written all the relationship this way:

```
CREATE DOMAIN origine
AS VARCHAR(6) DEFAULT NULL
CHECK (value ='upload' or value = 'link');

CREATE TABLE progetto.Utente (
ID_Utente VARCHAR(4) check (ID_Utente like ‘U%’),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Utente),
Username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE INDEX progetto.IDX_Utente_ID_Utente
ON progetto.Utente (ID_Utente);

CREATE TABLE progetto.Bacheca (
ID_Bacheca VARCHAR(4) check (ID_Bacheca like ‘B%’),
ID_Proprietario VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Bacheca),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Proprietario) references progetto.Utente (ID_Utente)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
Titolo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
N_follower INT
);

CREATE TABLE progetto.Immagine (
ID_Img VARCHAR(4) check (ID_Img like ‘I%’),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Img),
Origine origine,
Descrizione VARCHAR(20) default NULL,
Bacheca VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Bacheca) references progetto.Bacheca (ID_Bacheca)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
Possessore VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Possessore) references progetto.Utente (ID_Utente)
on update cascade
on delete cascade
N_pin INT NOT NULL,
N_like INT NOT NULL,
N_preferiti INT NOT NULL,
ID_Preferito VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Preferito) references progetto.Utente (ID_Utente)
on update cascade
on delete cascade
);

CREATE TABLE progetto.Topic (
ID_topic VARCHAR(4) check (ID_topic like ‘T%’),
PRIMARY KEY (ID_topic),
Nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE progetto.Correlazione (
Immagine VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Immagine) references progetto.Immagine (ID_Img)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
Topic VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Topic) references progetto.Topic (ID_topic)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
PRIMARY KEY (Immagine, Topic)
);

CREATE TABLE progetto.Pin (
Utente VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Utente) references progetto.Utente (ID_Utente)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
Immagine VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Immagine) references progetto.Immagine (ID_Img)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
PRIMARY KEY (Utente, Immagine)
);

CREATE TABLE progetto.Likes (
Utente VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Utente) references progetto.Utente (ID_Utente)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
Immagine VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Immagine) references progetto.Immagine (ID_Img)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
PRIMARY KEY (Utente, Immagine)
);

CREATE TABLE progetto.FollowBacheca (
Utente VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Utente) references progetto.Utente (ID_Utente)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
Bacheca VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Bacheca) references progetto.Bacheca (ID_Bacheca)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
PRIMARY KEY (Utente, Bacheca)
);

CREATE TABLE progetto.FollowUtenti (
Follower VARCHAR(4),
FOREIGN KEY (Follower) references progetto.Utente (ID_Utente)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
Followed VARCHAR(4),
FOREIGN KEY (Followed) references progetto.Utente (ID_Utente)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
PRIMARY KEY (Follower, Followed)
);

CREATE TABLE progetto.Affinità (
Topic1 VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Topic1) references progetto.Topic (ID_topic)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
Topic2 VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Topic2) references progetto.Topic (ID_topic)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
PRIMARY KEY (Topic1, Topic2)
);
```

Note: attributes in *italic* are foreign keys, **bold** primary keys.

- Utente (**ID_Utente**, Username)
- Bacheca (**ID_Bacheca**, *ID_Proprietario*, Titolo, N_follower)
- Immagine (**ID_img**, Origine, Descrizione, *Bacheca* , *Possessore*, N_pin, N_like, N_preferiti, *ID_Preferito* ) Origine ∈ {UPLOAD, LINK} Descrizione can be NULL
- Topic (**ID_topic**, Nome)
- Correlazione ( ***Immagine , Topic*** )
- Pin ( ***Utente , Immagine*** )
- Likes ( ***Utente , Immagine*** )
- FollowBacheca ( ***Utente , Bacheca*** )
- FollowUtenti (***Follower, Followed*** )
- Attinenza (***Topic1, Topic2*** )

Now I've got a problem. I want, when I DELETE a "Utente" (User) that the "Immagine" he is in relashionship "Possesso" with, is deleted only if that "Immagine"'s Origine is 'link'.

I think I have to use a trigger, but I'm not able to write one that does it.
Any suggestions?

PS: I'm sorry for the italian names.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should solve this with a trigger. First though, you should delete the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause from the `Immagine` table:

```
possessore varchar(4) NOT NULL REFERENCES progetto.Utente ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

The **trigger function** does the delete in table `Immagine`, if `origine = 'link'` and there is no row in table `Pin` that links the image to the user. Note that this assumes there is only one Immagine per Utente.

```
CREATE FUNCTION progetto.delete_immagine_origine_link() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  id_immagine varchar(4);
  org         origine;
BEGIN
    -- Check if an Immagine is linked to the Utente
    SELECT ID_Img, Origine INTO id_immagine, org
    FROM progetto.Immagine
    WHERE possessore = OLD.ID_Utente;
    IF FOUND THEN
        -- There is a row, but if the origine is wrong, fail the delete
        IF org != 'link' THEN
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;

        -- Now check if there is a Pin row that links Immagine to Utente
        PERFORM * FROM progetto.Pin
        WHERE Utente = OLD.ID_Utente AND Immagine = id_immagine;
        IF FOUND THEN
            RETURN NULL; -- There is a link, fail the delete
        END IF;

        -- It is safe to delete the row from Immagine
        DELETE FROM progetto.Immagine
        WHERE ID_Img = id_immagine;
    END IF;

    -- Either there was no Immagine for the Utente or it has been deleted
    -- so safe to delete Utente
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The **trigger** itself should be defined on the `Utente` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_from_utente
    BEFORE DELETE ON progetto.Utente
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE progetto.delete_immagine_origine_link();
```

Comment: Mm.. it seems its working.
What if i want to add the bond that "Immagine" must NOT be into "Pin" relashionship with Utente also?

Comment: What does "NOT be into Pin relationship" mean? `N_pin` is a number; do you mean that `N_pin = 0` otherwise no delete?

Comment: NOT be in 

Pin (Utente, Immagine)